# Change table row color by dynamically updating the className

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, create-react-app

I created this `Typescript` class in an attempt to change the row color in a table. My aim was to dyanmically update the `className` for the `tr`. Everything displays as expected but nothing happend when I check/uncheck the box. How do I fix this?

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

let classname: string = "checkbox-row1";

function getColor(pvalue: boolean) {
  if (pvalue) {
    classname = "checkbox-row1-red";
  }
  else {
    classname = "checkbox-row1-blue";
  }
}

export default function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <div className="checkbox-div">
          <table className="checkbox-table">
            <tr className={classname}>
              <td className="checkbox-row1"><label className="my-label">Check: <input type="checkbox" onClick={() => getColor(true)} name="change-color"></input></label></td>
              <td className="tr2-td2">2</td>
              <td className="tr3-td3">3</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
}

.App-logo {
  height: 40vmin;
  pointer-events: none;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
  .App-logo {
    animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear;
  }
}

.App-header {
  background-color: #282c34;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
  color: white;
}

.App-link {
  color: #61dafb;
}

@keyframes App-logo-spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.checkbox-row1 {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.checkbox-row1-blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.checkbox-row1-red {
  background-color: red;
}

.my-label {
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to store your `classname` variable in state. Currently it is changing value, but that doesn't trigger a re-render so the DOM is never updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the React hook useState() inside a React component. (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)
When state changes, the re-render will update your row class as expected.

```
import { useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
    const [classname,setClassname] = useState<string>("checkbox-row1");

    function getColor(pvalue: boolean) {
      if (pvalue) {
         setClassname("checkbox-row1-red");
      }
      else {
        setClassname("checkbox-row1-blue");
      }

return ( ...
```

Comment: Thanks. That was a big help. Out of curiosity. That only seems to be called when the box is checked. Is there an uncheck action that can be set?

Comment: No problem, glad it was helpful.  Your onClick function on the input element of type checkbox always calls your getColor() function with "true", which is probably why it appears that it only works when the box is checked.

Comment: (For a simple toggle, instead of requiring the pvalue parameter in getColor, you could simply check the current value of className in the getColor function:   if (classname==="checkbox-row1-red") setClassname("checkbox-row1-blue") else setClassname("checkbox-row1-red").  Does that make sense?)

Comment: That's exactly what I'm after. Thnks. You've been a massive help.